# Weirdest repeat call of function ever

Tags: javascript, function, validation

I made a questionnaire form that has a problem with the validation. There are several validating functions, that are called when clicking the submit button. But the first validating function is then called twice. To show the problem, I made a bare bones version that has the same problem. This is the whole source code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Demo Double Call</title>
</head>
<body>
<form name="upssForm" action="submit.php" method="POST" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
    A1 <input type="radio" name="A" value="1">
    A2 <input type="radio" name="A" value="2"><br>
    B1 <input type="radio" name="B" value="1">
    B2 <input type="radio" name="B" value="2"><br>
    <button type="button" onclick="validateForm()">Validate and submit button</button><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Validate and submit input">
</form>
<script>
function checkA() {
    var radioA = upssForm.elements['A'];
    if (radioA[0].checked == false) {
        alert('A1 not checked');
        return false;
    }
    else return true;
}

function checkB() {
    var radioB = upssForm.elements['B'];
    if (radioB[0].checked == false) {
        alert('B1 not checked');
        return false;
    }
    else return true;
}

function validateForm() {
    checkA();
    checkB();
    if ((checkA() == false) || (checkB() == false))
        return false;
    else
        upssForm.submit();
        // return true; /* doesn't work either with the submit input */
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Just click the submit button or the submit input, and see that the alert 'A1 not checked' comes up twice, the second time after the function checkB() is executed. What is causing this, and how do I solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling `checkA()` twice, once at the beginning of `validateForm()` and once in the `if()` statement.

Store the result in a variable, and then check that in the `if()` statement:

```
var aResult = checkA();
if(aResult == false) {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer WildCrustacean gave indeed solved the problem. For the record and future reference, I'll just give the whole function how it should be:

```
function validateForm() {
    var aResult = checkA();
    var bResult = checkB();
    if ((aResult == false) || (bResult == false))
        return false;
    else
        upssForm.submit();
}
```

Thanks, bro!

Answer (score 1):

WildCrustacean's answer is correct, so I've edited mine down. Just FYI, you might want to refactor your `if` statements. For example, `if (foo == false)` is the same as `if (!foo)` (although, interestingly, `if (foo === false)` is not). So, incorporating WildCrustacean's answer and taking out some redundant code:

```
function checkA() {
    var radioA = upssForm.elements['A'];
    if (!radioA[0].checked) {
        alert('A1 not checked');
    }
    return radioA[0].checked;
}

//function checkB() { ...

function validateForm() {
    var a = checkA();
    var b = checkB();
    if (a && b) {
        upssForm.submit();
    } 
    return false;
}
```

It's okay that `validateForm` always returns `false`, because the only time that affects anything is when the user clicks the input (not the button) while the form is invalid.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5GA5F/2/

In fact, if you don't mind odd-looking code, you can take advantage of Boolean short-circuiting to shrink the code even more:

```
function checkA() {
    var radioA = upssForm.elements['A'];
    return radioA[0].checked || alert('A1 not checked');
}

function checkB() {
    var radioB = upssForm.elements['B'];
    return radioB[0].checked || alert('B1 not checked');
}

function validateForm() {
    var a = checkA(),
        b = checkB();
    return a && b && upssForm.submit();
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5GA5F/3/

Comment: +1: this addresses a lot of things that need to be addressed in the current code.

Comment: Without the `return true`, the form is submitted also, without any error report from Firebug. With regards to the 'tailoring' of the code: that is appreciated.

Comment: @FrankConijn - Interesting, it didn't submit when I tried it. I'm going to edit that part out until I'm sure it's correct. Either way, glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to do it:

```
function validateForm() {
    if ((result = (checkA() && checkB()))){
        upssForm.submit();
    }

    return result;
}
```

This way, your function *always* returns information on whether it succeeds or not.  Another thing to notice here: in JavaScript, assignment statements return the value of the assignment.  We didn't have to assign the result value separately because we could call it in the `if` condition.

One thing to keep in mind: `checkB()` will only run if `checkA()` succeeds.  If you need them both to execute, assign their values to a variable and then check those variables.